Cual es la diferencia entre usar var o let en javascript?
en este codigo se estoy intentando imprimir mis dos variables (una declarada con let y otra declarada con var) sin embargo solo se imprime una de ellas. Por que no se imprime la variable y?
function ejemplo() {
    if (true) {
        var x = 10;
        let y = 20;
    }
    console.log(x); 
    console.log(y);
}

ejemplo(); 


Un statement es un bloque de código enmarcado entre corchetes { }. let solo vive dentro del bloque declarado, en cambio var no

Hola David, bienvenido, redondeando la respuesta de Yussef, podríamos decir que let "vive"  entre los corchetes más cercanos, var entre los corchetes de una función, y por supuesto, si no hay función y/o no hay corchetes,.. "viviran por siempre!".. PD: perdón por la pavada final.
